# Add dataLables to pie Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add labels to my pie Highchart so that the label shows the category and amount like in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic)
 Here is my code:

```js
$('#ro-tier-1').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Nx8zcIi0ULxytLmra0A9N11-llzJCDVH2-7SbK_k5-U',
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 1,
    startRow: 0,
    endRow: 3,
    googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 16
  },
  plotOptions: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{y}',
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Tier 1 Schools in 2012, 2013, or 2014 Expansion or Ceiling increase '
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 25,
    tickInterval: 5,
    title: {
      text: 'Amount of Schools'
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: 'Result'
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/modules/broken-axis.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="ro-tier-1"></div>

</body>
```

I know my issue is in the format for the data lables,  but API documentation is pretty sparse on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to place your dataLabels in correct plotOptions and use point

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}:{point.y}',
    }
  }
}
```

You can see a working sample here http://plnkr.co/edit/5VI6cAqVoIibhAJ8pYfP

UPDATE

Formatting can also work with {y} *format: '{y}'*, but if you want more advanced expression referencing via point is essential

Comment: You've done it again Igor! Where can I find the proper referrincing language. [Highcharts docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) and [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.format) only give examples and not a full list of what you can use.

Comment: It was not on purpose. In fact you are just one line above the description you need I suppose http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter contains all the "entry points" available

Comment: I saw that, but the formats say "this" instead of "point". I guess I'm just confused as to how you deduced that the reference needed to be point.y and note this.y.